# difference between DetectChange and ChangeTracking in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i am reading this [topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx) on MSDN

can any one please explain me that what is difference between these two as mention

> **DetectChanges** is use to detect the changes in DBContext and related Entities

and

> **ChangeTracking** is also use to detect changes in Entity as mentioned in this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx)

please explain me the actual difference betweeen theese two.

Answer (score 1):

So EF needs to detect changes you make to the context, like adding\modifying\removing entities. Entities might be plain POCO entities and so have no embedded behaviour to track changes to their properties. So EF should make a snapshot of the entities it receives from database and then compare this database snapshot with actual state of the context. Even more - EF should track relationships between objects in the context and keep them synchronized. All this is done by method called DetectChanges(). It is being called at various moments, most importantly when you call SaveChanges, but also when you add\remove\attach entities to the context and so on.

If you design your entity classes in a special way (all properties virtual, collections represented by ICollection etc) - you can use automatic change tracking. EF will create special proxy classes inherited from your entity classes and will use that to immediatly detect changes to your entity properties. Note that DetectChanges is still used in this case, exactly as described above. But it performs less work, since most of the changes are already detected right when they happened.

Summary: DetectChanges is a method to perform snapshot-based change detection (and more) and is a part of the group of ways used by Entity Framework to track (detect) changes to the context. Read more about DetectChanges here: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/